# Components are not showing when the routes changing in vue (Vue3, Vue-router)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm new in Vue(v.3) and vue-router, **before** I share the problem with you guys, **I searched it inside Stack Overflow and google, but the problem still unresolved.**

I define two routes:

1. /login
2. /admin/index

**Problem:**

the login route is working correctly. but
when I try to go to the admin route, it displays the login form instead of the admin panel.

**NOTE :**  I declared `<router-view></router-view>` inside `components/layouts/MasterComponent.vue`, and inside `App.vue` ,I just import the login component.

Here is my code:

**routes:**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import LoginComponent from "../components/auth/LoginComponent";
import MasterComponent from "../components/layouts/MasterComponent";
import ProjectComponent from "../components/ProjectsComponent.vue";
const routes = [{
        name: "Login",
        path: "/login",
        component: LoginComponent,
    },

    // admin routes
    {
        name: "Index",
        path: "/admin/index",
        component: MasterComponent,
        children: [{
            path: '/admin/projects',
            name: 'Projects',
            component: ProjectComponent,
        }]
    },
];
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

**Master component code:**

```
    <template>
    <div class="app">
        <HeaderComponent />
        <LeftMenu />
        <div class="main-content">
          <section class="section">
            <div class="section-body">
              <!-- add content here -->
              <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
          </section>
          <SiteSetting/>
        </div>
        <FooterComponent />
    </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import HeaderComponent from "./HeaderComponent.vue";
    import LeftMenu from "./LeftMenu.vue";
    import FooterComponent from "./FooterComponent.vue";
    import SiteSetting from "./SiteSetting.vue";
    export default {
      name: "MasterComponent",
      components: {
        HeaderComponent,
        LeftMenu,
        FooterComponent,
        SiteSetting
    },
    };
    </script>
```

**App.vue code**

```
<template>
  <LoginComponent/>
</template>

<script>
import LoginComponent from './components/auth/LoginComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    LoginComponent
}
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**main.js code**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import routes from "./routes/route";
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(routes)
app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: The `path` for child routes should be relative to their parent. So in your case, the projects page would be accessible under `/admin/index/admin/projects`. You can fix it, by setting the parent path to `/admin`, then the child path to `projects`, and have it accessible under `/admin/projects`.

Comment: I fix it,but it still displays the login component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I just forgot to put `<router-view></router-view>` inside `App.vue`. and also change the routes like this:

```
// admin routes
    {
        name: "Index",
        path: "/admin",
        component: MasterComponent,
        redirect: '/dashboard',
        children: [{
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'Dashboard',
            component: DashboardComponent,
        }]
    },
```

**`App.vue` before changes:**

```
<template>
  <LoginComponent/>
</template>

<script>
import LoginComponent from './components/auth/LoginComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    LoginComponent
}
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**`App.vue` after changes:**

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
}
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```